# How do I make my screen resolution from 1024 x 600 to a 1024 x 728 resolution? (notebook)

Tags: laptop, resolution

I have a Toshiba notebook which has a 1024 x 600 screen resolution. But to run some programs, it requires a higher resolution. How can I can solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't there an option in right-click>Screen Resolution?

Comment: Thank u for the comment but, my highest resolution is 1024 x 600. However, there was a user who said that screen resolution can be further adjusted. Link-http://superuser.com/questions/506792/how-to-increase-the-screen-resolution-from-1024x600-to-1024x768-on-hp-mini-210-4/506796#506796

Comment: If 1024x600 is the native resolution of the screen, going higher will have a price.  Some graphics controllers have the equivalent of a zoom feature, and there is some 3rd party software that will do this.  However, the results are not very usable.  Once you start interpolating and averaging to fit the content to the screen, edges get degraded so nothing looks sharp or in focus, and detail disappears.  It can be adequate to navigate to what you want to focus on, but it will give you eye strain trying to work in it.

Comment: I was able to change my screen resolution  to a bigger size

Comment: @AYYA If you managed to find a solution, please help out future visitors and add it as an answer.